# Properties of a specific Complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider a map $f_{p,q}$ from $\mathbb{C}^2$ to $\mathbb{C}$ is defined as $f_{p.q}(z,w)=\frac{p+q.z}{1+w}$ where the $p$ and $q$ are two complex numbers.

What can we talk about continuity, differentiability, analyticity and other properties of the function?

Comment: Assuming your domain is $\{ (z,w) \in \mathbb{C}^2 : w\neq -1 \}$ the function is continuous and analytic in both variables, so in particular it is continuous and differentiable.

Comment: Can you please give me a formal proof. I am unable to succeed.

Comment: Are you, Sk, able to prove that $z$ is continuous and differentiable? How about $qz$? $p+qz$? $w$? $1+w$? If you can do those, then all that's left is showing the quotient of functions with those properties has those properties. And if you can't prove $z$ is continuous, how do you come to be studying functions of several complex variables?

Comment: Professor, Myerson, Thanks for inputs. I am a layman unlike you. But does analyticity would follow similar logic?

Comment: Analyticity follows from complex differentiability, just like in one variable.